# How can I take QUANTITY of all issues in GitHub API without all information about them

Tags: api, github

Have one question about GitHub API. I see that you can take all issues in JSON file by typing: http://api.github.com/users/issues - but this wil lreturn JSON file with all issues and I need only NUMBER of them. Can I take the quantity of issues of the repo without all info about them?
Need this to create pagination.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. If somebody interested in:
https://api.github.com/repos/{user}/{repo} - you ahve field called "open_issues" - and there is number of all opened issues.